# benefit in using operator invoke in functional interfaces

Tags: kotlin

I am just wondering what is the benefit of using the operator invoke than not using it. I am trying it out on one of my interfaces to see what the benefits are.

```
fun interface MapperDomainToData<in E, out M> {
    operator fun invoke(entity: E): M
}

fun interface MapperDomainToData<in E, out M> {
    fun map(entity: E): M
}
```

In my implementation there seems to be no difference. In fact I prefer not using it as the method name is more meaningful.

```
class MapSocialLoginRequestImp @Inject constructor() : MapperDomainToData<SocialLoginRequestEntity, SocialLoginRequestModel> {
    override fun invoke(entity: SocialLoginRequestEntity): SocialLoginRequestModel {
        return SocialLoginRequestModel(
            token = entity.token,
            provider = entity.provider
        )
    }

    override fun map(entity: SocialLoginRequestEntity): SocialLoginRequestModel {
        return SocialLoginRequestModel(
            token = entity.token,
            provider = entity.provider
        )
    }
}
```

I think the second implementation is the more clear as the `map` method is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference isn't in how you declare the interface implementation, but only in how you *use* the interface object.  Of course there's no difference in your code.

The difference is between

```
myMapper(entity)
```

and

```
myMapper.map(entity)
```

To be clear, it's entirely reasonable to prefer the second one, but that's the difference that the `invoke` operator function provides.

Comment: Indeed. Reduces the scope of your dependencies and/or how you inject them.